# how does this General Assembly website fade in?

Tags: html, css, fade

it looks like http://www.generalassemb.ly/ has set the container to 0 opacity, i'm just curious if it's faded in by javascript or css3. seems like a great way to load a complete page.

Comment: CSS technically doesn't do animations, but Javascript modifying CSS on a timed/repeating basis does make it look animated. Rather like a single frame of a cartoon isn't moving, but many of them together give the illusion of movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in app.js it's animating using jquery.

```
$(window).load(function() {
 $('#container').show();   

 $('#loading').animate({
    opacity: 0
   }, 200, function () {
    $('#loading').hide();
   });

 $("#container").animate({
    opacity: 1
   }, 1000);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, using Jquery. Although it's possible to make these sort of transitions with CSS3 [take a look here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-timing-function_tag).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: take a look at the view-->source of the page. It is, imo, extraordinarily clean markup. You'll be able to follow everything very easily. An hour spent studying the source will be very helpful and instructivefor you and will give you some great insights. So much so that you'll never again have to ask a question like yours. You'll be *answering* such questions instead :-)

Comment: yep i just couldn't find it. i agree though, it's amazing that we can see the source